# Cannot convert BsonArray to BsonDocument in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have my Json string as

```
string myjson = "[
{
    "col1": "1",
    "col2": "2",
    "col3": "3"
},
{
    "col1": "4",
    "col2": "5",
    "col3": "6"
},
{
    "col1": "7",
    "col2": "8",
    "col3": "9"
}]";
```

Problem is : When i am creating bson document it is showing

> Cannot convert BsonArray to BsonDocument

This is how I'm creating the BsonDocument :

```
BsonDocument doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjson);
```

What should i do?

Comment: your json starts with square brackets, which shows that the object is an array, but bsondocument.parse excepts it to be a valid json object (BsonDocument). You should create BsonDocument like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6274023/1817929

Comment: Same problem, BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjson) expects myjson to be of BsonDocument format (JSON object), but it is of BsonArray format (JSON array)

Comment: ok now i am getting it, so what should i do now? Actually i am getting that string myjson, so how should i create BsonDocument out of that string?

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş thank you for this gem `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjson)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument();
BsonArray array = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(myjson);
doc.Add(array);
```

I didn't try it but it should work.

**Edit:**

```
        string myjson1 = "{ 'col1': '1', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3'}";
        string myjson2 = "{ 'col1': '4', 'col2': '5', 'col3': '6'}";
        string myjson3 = "{'col1': '7', 'col2': '8', 'col3': '9'}";

        BsonArray arr = new BsonArray();
        arr.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjson1));
        arr.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjson2));
        arr.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjson3));
```

or simply have a `values` element inside the document like this:

```
string myjson = "[ { 'col1': '1', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3'},{ 'col1': '4', 'col2': '5', 'col3': '6'},{'col1': '7', 'col2': '8', 'col3': '9'}]";    
var doc = new BsonDocument {
                    { "values", BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(myjson) }
                };
```

The best that I could do is this.

Comment: getting this "cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonElement'"

Answer (score 2):

Or a cleaner way :

```
var arrayDocs = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(myJsonArrayString);
 var documents = arrayDocs.Select(val => val.AsBsonDocument);
```

which will give you an `IEnumerable<BsonDocument>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert BsonArray to array of BsonValue, then iterate through that array:

```
var a = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(yourjsontext).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
  var document = a[i].ToBsonDocument();
  // Do whatever necessary
}
```